# React with JavaScript or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**React with JavaScript or TypeScript?**

which is best if typescript is  please explain why it is.

Comment: React provides the prop types and so I don't think we need to use typescript.

Comment: Clone this boilerplate for TypeScript + React and open in VS Code to see the benefits of type checking: https://github.com/styfle/react-server-example-tsx

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on the size and type of the project. If a small project is developed by, for example, only one developer is sufficient for JS, if one is a large enterprise solution, then it is a better typecript.

The TypeScrip main features:

- optional static typing (the key here is optional)
- type Inference, which gives some of the benefits of types
- access to ES6 and ES7 features
- the ability to compile down to a version of JavaScript that runs on all browsers

Comment: #3 & #4 aren't exclusive to typescript only